# Is it possible to automatically scroll down the web page all the way down with code?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing web scraping for a certain webpage and I have noticed that my code only scrapes the part where only the first scroll is showing. The page automatically shows more info when scrolled down further with some loading. Here is the code that seems to control such algorithm.

```
<div class="view-pagination text-right">
   <ul class="js-pager__items pager" data-drupal-views-infinite-scroll-pager="automatic">
      ::before
      <li class="pager__item">
         <div class="ajax-progress ajax-progress-throbber">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin">
               ::before
            </i>
         </div>
         <a class="button visually-hidden" href="some_links_here" title="Go to next page" rel="next">Load More</a>
      </li>
      ::after
   </ul>
</div>
```

I am using BeautifulSoup library in Python for web scraping. Could anyone help how I can let my code scrape the entire info of the page (none of info hidden because I didn't scroll the page)?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using selenium for this task.  I would scroll to the bottom of the page and then scrape the html using BeautifulSoup.